# Steigend vs. zunehmend: what's the difference?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I originally wrote *steigend* but it was corrected to *zunehmend* - why?

Here's the text:
*Wie nie zuvor werden Menschen überwacht, nicht nur in Banken und in teuren Läden, sondern auch auf der Straße, in öffentlichen Gebäuden und **(steigend) zunehmend** in Schulen.*

Comment: "auf ***der*** Straße", Dativ, wie schon ganz richtig "in öffentliche-n Gebäude-n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"steigend" and the underlying verb "steigen" are typically used with some kind of height, literally or figuratively.

> Der steigende Wasserstand löst die nächste Warnstufe aus.

> The rising water level triggers the next warning level.

or

> Die steigenden Sicherheitsanforderungen stellen viele Unternehmen vor Herausforderungen.

> The rising security requirements are a challenge for many companies.

But in your example, there's no height involved, neither literally nor figuratively. So "steigend" isn't a good choice. "Zunehmend" is used with things that can increase or accumulate, regardless how that increase would express itself spatially.

Comment: I understand! But could "zunehmend" be used in your two examples? Der zunehmende Wasserstand, die zunehmende Sicherheitsanforderungen? Danke sehr!

Comment: @Tamaz "Zunehmend" could be used in those two examples, but it would sound a bit off in my opinion. By the way, it would be "die zunehmenden Sicherheitsanforderungen", in plural.

Comment: perfect, I'll keep that in mind, thanks! And yes, of course, die zunehmendeN Sicherheitsanforderungen, when will I learn the Adjektivdeklination?!? Vielen Dank!

Comment: @Tamaz I'd like to emphasize that it isn't wrong. You can say what you did and will be understood. Just as Henning has said in his answer, zunehmend is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

"zunehmend" ist als Adverb bezogen auf die Verbalphrase "werden Menschen überwacht" zu verstehen.

Mir fällt kein Beispiel ein, in dem "steigend" ein Adverb wäre. Es ist häufig als Adjektiv in ähnlichem Sinne anzutreffen, dennoch auf Nominalphrasen bezogen, woraus mittels Präposition eine Adverbialphrase wird, a) "die *steigende* Tendenz der Kurse", b) "Seine Aufmerksamkeit erhöhte sich *in steigendem* Maße" ([dwds.de/wb/steigen 4. b) und c)](https://dwds.de/wb/steigen)). In diesem Sinne ist es eine grammatikalische Frage.

Lexikalisch ist der Unterschied im wesentlichen wie English "increasingly" zu verstehen, dasist weder "ascending", "rising", noch "climbing".

---

Jedoch sind beide Wörter Partizipien, das macht eine scharfe grammatikalische Trennung in Adverb und Adjektiv schwierig, gerade im Deutschen, wo der unterschied nicht flektiert wird.

Bemerke, dass *zu-nehmen* die Präposition bereits enthält. Daneben findet sich ebenso *ansteigen* in ähnlichem Sinne auch mit Präposition. Dies sind übrigens trennbar zusammengesetzte Verben, *Der Wert steigt an* (auch genannt Particle Verb, cf. Putnam, Biskup, Smith 2010). Die Betonung liegt auf der Präposition.

Zwar kann steigend theoretisch auch als gewöhnliches Partizip Präsenz verstanden und in diesem Sinne gewöhnlich als Adverb verwendet werden, zumal dieses *s-* womöglich aus einem Preverb herrührt, das aber nicht mehr erkennbar ist (siehe "s-mobile" im Urindogermanischen, ungeklärt). Allerdings wird sich die gewollte Aussage daraus kaum erschließen. Der Ausdruck "zunehmend" ist idiomatisch, anders definiert als "steigen", auch wenn Überschneidungen vorliegen, die hier eben nicht relevant sind.

> 1. "[lange Aufzählung ... ] und zunehmend in Schulen"

Vermutlich lässt gerade das gegebene Beispiel darauf schließen, dass eher eine Konjunktion mit inklusiver Bedeutung zugrunde liegt, vgl. *zuzüglich*, *hinzukommend*. In dieser Lesart, die einem "steigen" völlig fehlt, wäre die Bedeutung der Zunahme schlicht implizit vorausgesetzt.

Im Gegensatz zur Gewichtszunahme fehlt denn auch das einfache Komplement... So ist weder  von *Überwachtwerdenanstieg, eben so wenig von *Überwachtwerdenanstieg, noch von *Überwachungszunahme zu reden. Ob nun wie eben behauptet die Überwachung an Schulen zunimmt, oder umgekehrt, sei dahingestellt (es ist ein komplexes argument). Diese Doppeldeutigkeit (auch *semantically underspecified*) ist hier nicht weiter aufzulösen.

> 2. Die Überwachung nimmt *zu* sehr Überhand

Zu bemerken bleibt doch noch, "zu" drückt regelmäßig auch negative Polarität aus, "Das geht *zu* weit!".

Beide Ansätze lassen sich auch in Englisch "too" erahnen. Die negative Polarität ist auch weitläufig in Latein "de-" ersichtlich, das von der gleichen Wurzel abstammend sonst nahezu entgegengesetzte Bedeutungen erfahren hat.

Comment: The question is in english. Your answer isn‘t.... I think therefor the downvote (though its not from me)

Comment: @Torsten Link: I think the the main point is that *steigend* would rarely be used as an adverb, perhaps something like "ascendingly" in English. Not that it's impossible: "The pieces in the Well-Tempered Clavier are arranged in ascendingly ordered keys." But definitely not for the intended meaning in this case..